# equivalence relation with binary and decimal numbers

Tags: equivalence-relations

I am learning about relations and I was hoping to find out if my attempt for my question looks right.

Let b(n) equal the value of the highest bit set to 1 in the binary representation of the positive integer n. (For example, b(27)=16 because in 27= $11011_2$ and the most significant bit set to one is the first bit on the left, which has value $2^4$.)

Prove that the relation, R, defined below over the set of integers in between 0 and 1023, inclusive, is an equivalence relation. Into how many equivalence classes does R partition the set described? Explicitly list all of the members of the following equivalence classes: [2] and [13]. Let the set X be the largest of the equivalence classes. What is the smallest integer that belongs to X?

$$R = \{ (x,y)  | b(x) = b(y) \} $$

- R is reflexive as $b(i) = b(i) $ for all $i \in Z$.
- R is symmetric as $b(i) = b(j) \rightarrow b(j) = b(i)$
- R is transitive as $b(i) = b(j) \wedge B(j) = b(k)$ then $b(i) = b(k)$

[2] = $ \{2, 2 \} $ (2 in binary is 10)

[13] = $ \{13, 4 \} $ (13 in binary is 1101)

Would 512 make sense to be the smallest integer?

Comment: Your equivalence classes are incorrect. For example, $[2]=\{2,3\}$ and $[13]=\{8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\}$ and

Comment: @AnuragA the largest 1 in binary form of 2 is (10). How would it be three?

Comment: The binary representation of $3=(11)_2$. So $b(3)=2$. Thus $2$ and $3$ are *equivalent* under this relation. Another way to understand this relation is as follows: two integers are related if the highest power of $2$ that is less than or equal to those integers is same.